# "Object moved to here." text is in the wrong position on Stack Overflow Chat's error page

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, 404-not-found

[On the HTTP version of the Stack Overflow chat error page](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/nevergonnagiveyouup), the "Object moved to here." text is in the wrong position and it's barely even visible. (I'm not sure why the text is even there, it should automatically redirect me to the HTTPS page IMO.)

[image]

I'm using Safari 11.0.3 and macOS 10.13.3.

Comment: Reproducible Vivaldi/Windows 10.

Comment: And Chrome/Firefox/Edge Windows 10

Comment: I appreciate the name of the chat room you've linked to. In a "haha, you got me this time" kinda way.

Comment: Never gonna let you down.

Comment: Similarly, if you go to the https version of that same page the footer is messed up: https://imgur.com/O4aRUVv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It now simply redirects to the HTTPS version, just as I suggested.

Comment: Doesn't that tag go in the OP?

Comment: @msanford It does, it's just semantics. Also note that it can only be added by a moderator.

Comment: But doesn't it not show up in listing, search, etc? (Still learning Meta!)

Comment: @msanford No, you cannot tag answers. I'm just using the `[meta-tag:xyz]` formatting.

Comment: Indeed. I meant: is it not customary to edit the question and add the [meta-tag:status-completed] to the question in order for it to appear in listings, search, etc? Or is that usually done by a mod or a developer? Or just in a different context?

Comment: @msanford It **is** customary. I flagged the question for the need of moderator intervention.